# Combobox selected value not getting

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

This is function that I used to load combobox. I can load combobox but when I try to get `selectedvalue` of combobox it showing `null`; I am not getting the actual value.

```
public static DataTable GetComboBoxedDataTable(DataTable oldDataTable, string valueColumn, string textColumn, string topRowValue, string topRowText, ComboBox cmb)
{
    DataTable newDataTable = new DataTable();
    newDataTable.Columns.Add(valueColumn);
    newDataTable.Columns.Add(textColumn);
    foreach (DataRow oldDR in oldDataTable.Rows)
    {
        DataRow newDR = newDataTable.NewRow();
        newDR[0] = oldDR[valueColumn].ToString();
        newDR[1] = oldDR[textColumn].ToString();
        newDataTable.Rows.InsertAt(newDR, newDataTable.Rows.Count);
    }

    // Add your 'Select an item' option at the top
    DataRow dr = newDataTable.NewRow();
    dr[0] = topRowValue;
    dr[1] = topRowText;
    newDataTable.Rows.InsertAt(dr, 0);

    cmb.ValueMember = valueColumn;
    cmb.DisplayMember = textColumn;
    return newDataTable;
}
```

The code to fill combobox :

```
PolosysHMS.General.Classes.GeneralClass.GetComboBoxedDataTable(ds.Tables[0], "RoomID", "RoomNo", "0", "Select", cmbroomno);
```

the code where i am in need of combobox.selectedvalue :

```
private void cmbroomno_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                object[,] ParamArray = new object[,] { { "@RoomID", cmbroomno.SelectedValue } };---code where i need selected value
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                ds = DB.ExecuteQuery_SP("SelectGuestDetailsForService", ParamArray);
```

The code to fill combobox :

Comment: show the code how you are getting the selected value.

Comment: Where did you set DataSource for combo?

Comment: //DataSet ds = DB.ExecuteQuery_SP("SelectRoomsByCheckStatus");
            //PolosysHMS.General.Classes.GeneralClass.GetComboBoxedDataTable(ds.Tables[0], "RoomID", "RoomNo", "0", "Select", cmbroomno);

Comment: check your valueColumn is correctly passing to GetComboBoxedDataTable method.

Comment: Datasource had tables and combobox also binding but selected value is showing null....

Comment: ya i checked......by failing this method i used another method..  //DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            //ds = DB.ExecuteQuery_SP("SelectRoomsByCheckStatus");
            //if (ds.Tables.Count > 0)
            //{

            //    cmbroomno.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
            //    cmbroomno.DisplayMember = "RoomNo";
            //    cmbroomno.ValueMember = "RoomID";
            //}

Comment: Its working fine but i want to shorten the code....

Comment: why you create a new table inside GetComboBoxedDataTable method? without binding directly from dataset

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you should change your code to fill the combobox. its look weird.

```
public static DataTable GetComboBoxedDataTable(DataTable oldDataTable, string valueColumn, string textColumn, string topRowValue, string topRowText, ComboBox cmb)
{
    DataTable newDataTable = oldDataTable.Copy();
    DataRow dr = newDataTable.NewRow();
    dr[0] = topRowValue;
    dr[1] = topRowText;
    newDataTable.Rows.InsertAt(dr, 0);

    cmb.ValueMember = valueColumn;
    cmb.DisplayMember = textColumn;
    cmb.DataSource = newDataTable;
    return newDataTable;
}
```

Second thing you are declaring a multi dimensional array to store the value

```
private void cmbroomno_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    object[,] ParamArray = new object[,] { { "@RoomID", cmbroomno.SelectedValue } };
    DataSet ds = DB.ExecuteQuery_SP("SelectGuestDetailsForService", ParamArray);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed to set the DataSet.

```
cmb.DataSource = newDataTable 
cmb.ValueMember = valueColumn;
cmb.DisplayMember = textColumn;
return newDataTable;
```

Comment: for datasource datatable is enough...if we are using dataset we are choosing a table in it.....

Comment: you said you are not getting value of the selected item ? right. its because your cmb datasource is null. just replace the code with my code and check.

Comment: Combobox is binding and showing data in combobox but when go for selected value it's showing null value if datasource is null how combobox will bind and showing data